# Set 2 NSPredicates on a NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I'm using Core Data and have a to-many relationship with the following entities:

`Athlete(evals)<-->>Eval(whosEval)`

It starts with a table view that lists ALL athletes in the database. Then when you select an Athlete it pulls up their Evals in a table view. The problem is the way I am doing this is through checking their full name. Unfortunately, it is possible for 2 athletes to have the same name. For this reason, I check their parent's name as well, but I think I am doing it incorrectly. Can anyone explain why the following doesn't work and how I should do it correctly? What happens with this code is if 2 Athletes have the same name, they'll share results. Even if their Parent's Name is different.

```
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSFetchRequest *athleteRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [athleteRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
    NSError *athleteError = nil;
    NSPredicate *athletePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full == %@", _athletesFullName];
    [athleteRequest setPredicate:athletePredicate];
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:athleteRequest error:&athleteError];
    if([results count] >1){
        NSPredicate *athletePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pfull == %@", _athletesParentsFullName];
        [athleteRequest setPredicate:athletePredicate];
    }

    Athlete *athleteSelected;

    if([results count] >0){
    Athlete *currentAthlete = [results objectAtIndex:0];
        athleteSelected = currentAthlete;
    }
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosEval == %@", athleteSelected];
   [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSEntityDescription *eval = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Eval" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:eval];
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `athleteRequest` after the request has been executed does not have 
any effect on the result. Why not simply

```
NSPredicate *athletePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full == %@ AND (pfull == nil OR pfull == %@)",
             _athletesFullName, _athletesParentsFullName];
```

?

Apart from that, it would probably be better to identify the objects by some
unique identifier (e.g. a unique athlete number) instead of relying on name
and parent's name.

Comment: Here's what happens. When I have 2 athletes with same names and different parent names, the first one is fine, the second athlete doesn't show the other's evals, _but_ whenever I add an eval to that athlete, it doesn't display on the table.

Comment: @user2674329: Sorry, but I don't understand. Your question was about how to fetch an athlete using 2 criteria and I have tried to answer that. You have not shown how you "add an eval to that athlete" so I cannot say why it does not work correctly.

Comment: @user2674329: One more remark: You can get the evals of an athlete just with `NSArray *evalsForAthlete = [athlete.evals allObjects]`, without executing another fetch request.

Comment: Thanks!! Started ios programming this summer, only 16, new to OOP. Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is really simple, but for more complex situations, you can use compound predicates.

Read this awesome article from NSHipster for more informations:
http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/